# How to split a string column into another one based on condition of other column in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
 dt = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['A','A_B']})
```

I would like for the `rows` that `col==A` to have the value `all` into a new column (`col2`) and for the rest to do a `str.split` operation

The final df I would like to look like this:

```
  dt = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['A', 'A_B'],
                         'col2': ['all', 'B']})
```

I tried:

```
dt['col2'] = np.where(dt.col == 'A', 'all',
                                 dt.col.apply(lambda x: x.split('_')[1]))
```

but I get this error: `IndexError: list index out of range`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If use pandas text functions it working correct in your situtation - return missing value, because second list not exist:

```
print (dt.col.str.split('_').str[1])
0    NaN
1      B
Name: col, dtype: object


dt['col2'] = np.where(dt.col == 'A', 'all', dt.col.str.split('_').str[1])
print (dt)
   col col2
0    A  all
1  A_B    B
```

Or use `[-1]` for select last lists after split:

```
dt['col2'] = np.where(dt.col == 'A',  'all',
                      dt.col.apply(lambda x: x.split('_')[-1]))
```

Or is possible filter values by inverting mask:

```
m = dt.col == 'A'
dt['col2'] = np.where(m, 'all',
                      dt.loc[~m, 'col'].apply(lambda x: x.split('_')[1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do

```py
dt['col2'] = dt.col.str.split('_', expand = True).fillna('all')[1]
```